# FFmpeg to Shoutcast - Right URL syntax

Tags: url, ffmpeg, syntax, shoutcast, internet-radio

I'm trying to stream mp3 audio to a shoutcast server.
I'm able to do that with icecast servers but the same syntax apparently can't work for shoutcast ones.
The main issues is: i have an hostname(IP), a port and a password. Stop.
With icecast i use icecast://username:pass@host:ip/mount.
But, for shoutcast, where do i have to put the password in a stream url?
I tried a few things like: http://pass@host:port or http://host:port/pass but they did not work.

Is anybody able to do this? Thank you! :)

P.S. Here is the command i run for stream to Icecast:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i pulse -c:a libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ab 128k -content_type 'adui/mpeg' -f mp3 icecast://user:pass@host:ip/mount
```

Comment: I don't think the `icecast://` module is compatible with the SHOUTcast source stream protocol.

Comment: Hi @Brad! Yes, the icecast:// you see in the script is only an example of what i've used for encode and stream to an Icecast server. The problem is that, assuming i only have an host, port and password, i really don't know which is the correct sytanx for the stream url. I assume it uses http protocol, but not sure about where to put the password.

Comment: SHOUTcast uses its own proprietary source stream protocol, not HTTP.  That's the problem.  Icecast actually does use something HTTP compatible.

Comment: Thank you Brad, I read that Shoutcast actually uses HTTP as a transport protocol. For example, if my host is HOST, my port is PORT and my password is PASSWORD (i don't have any source name or username), which will be the correct url for FFmpeg?

Comment: SHOUTcast uses HTTP for its output, but for the source stream it uses its own thing.  And, I don't think FFmpeg can stream to it.

Comment: Ok, thank you really much for the infos. Do you know any shoutcast encoder that works on command line? The OS used is Debian (Buster).

Comment: There's always `sc_trans`.  http://wiki.shoutcast.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_DNAS_Transcoder_2#Linux_.2F_Mac_OS_X_.2F_BSD